# How to delete item if exist using sqlite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I spend much time on **SQLite** and I have a problem in deleting an item if it **exist**!

I'm working in **Bookmark App** that save **links** from **webview** into **listview** using **SQLite**, my problem is can't check if the item is exist > don't create a link.

this is my **BookmarksDatabase** used for **sqlite**:

```
public class BookmarksDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bookmarks.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "bookmarks_data";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "ITEM1";
    private static final String COL3 = "ITEM2";

    public BookmarksDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " ITEM1 TEXT, " + " ITEM2 TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String item1, String item2) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item1);
        contentValues.put(COL3, item2);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        // if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        return result != -1;
    }
    public Cursor getListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    }

    public ArrayList<Bookmarks> getAllData() {
        ArrayList<Bookmarks> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            int id = data.getInt(0);
            String title = data.getString(1);
            String link = data.getString(2);
            Bookmarks bookmarks = new Bookmarks(id, title, link);

            arrayList.add(bookmarks);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }

    public int deleteSpecificContents(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL1 + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
    }
}
```

this is my code used in **MainActivity** to fetch items on **listview**

```
/*---------------- Bookmark Tab, sqlite databases integrated ---------------*/
    private void showBookmarksScreen() {

        // initialize a dialog in the main activity
        final Dialog bookmarksScreen = new Dialog(this);

        bookmarksScreen.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        bookmarksScreen.setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookmark);

        bookmarksScreen.setCancelable(true);

        final ListView listView = bookmarksScreen.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_list);
        RelativeLayout bookmarkEmpty = bookmarksScreen.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_empty);

        // create an array and call bookmark
        // database to retrive data then
        // fetch it into list view
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList = bookmarkDB.getAllData();

        // get all data from sqlite database
        Cursor data = bookmarkDB.getListContents();

        // check if no bookmarks
        // then show view that inform
        // user that there is no bookmarks
        if(data.getCount() == 0 ) {
            bookmarkEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        bookmarkListAdpater = new BookmarkListAdpater(this, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(bookmarkListAdpater);
        bookmarkListAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // load link on item click
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView link = view.findViewById(R.id.list_link);
                String convertedLink = link.getText().toString();
                webView.loadUrl(convertedLink);
                bookmarksScreen.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // ask user to delete bookmark on item long click
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                // initialize a dialog in the main activity
                final Dialog deleteDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                deleteDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                deleteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm);

                // confirm message or dialog can't be
                // canceled so we set it to false
                deleteDialog.setCancelable(false);

                TextView deleteMessage = deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_text);
                TextView deleteConfirm = deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_allow);
                TextView deleteCancel = deleteDialog.findViewById(R.id.confirm_deny);

                deleteMessage.setText(getString(R.string.delete_bookmark));

                // confirm button
                deleteConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Cursor data = bookmarkDB.getListContents();
                        int i = 0;
                        while(data.moveToNext()){
                            if(i == position){
                                break;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }

                        bookmarkDB.deleteSpecificContents(data.getInt(0));

                        deleteDialog.dismiss();
                        bookmarksScreen.dismiss();
                        customToast(getString(R.string.bookmark_deleted), 0);

                    }

                });

                // confirm cancel
                deleteCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        deleteDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                });

                deleteDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                deleteDialog.show();

                return true;
            }
        });

        bookmarksScreen.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        bookmarksScreen.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        bookmarksScreen.show();

    }
```

My **Model**

```
public class Bookmarks {

    int id;
    String title, link;

    public Bookmarks(int id, String title, String link) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
    }

    public  Bookmarks() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

any ideas? **thanks**.

Comment: Have you heard about Room? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Where is your data model that you set to ListView?

Comment: @ShankhadeepGhoshal Yes, but my school doesn't allow  me to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below to delete item from `DB`

```
bookmarkDB.deleteSpecificContents(arrayList.get(position).getId(0));
```

If you want to check item exists or not before adding then add below code in your `BookmarksDatabase`

```
public boolean isExists(String link) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL3 + "='" + link + "'", null);
    return cursor.getCount() > 0;
}
```

And then check

```
if(bookmarkDB.isExists(link))
    //Already Exist
else
    //Not Exist, add now
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me what this will do? I mean will it check if item is exist and delete it? in my app i have a button and when i click on it the button well get url and add it to sqlite, i want to check if url is exist then don't add it.

Comment: delete operation in SQLite delete item if exists otherwise not. If you want to check only exists then why you call delete?

Comment: I call deleteSpecificContents() to delete item if i want to delete it so i long click on it to delete but i want to check if item exist before adding item

Answer (score 1):

With the same logic you're using:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseManager(context).getWritableDatabase();

String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + ID_KEY + " = ?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});

if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
      db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID_KEY + " = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
}

cursor.close();
db.close();
```

Another possibility is changing the method return type to boolean and verifying the return count from the delete command:

```
public boolean deleteSpecificContents(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL1 + "=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)}) > 0;
}
```